# OpenText System Architecture Diagram

Tags: reddot, opentext

Does anyone know where I can find the System Architecture Diagram for reddot?

I know they are now Web Solutions Group.  If someone can retag this so it makes more sense that would be appreciated also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to check is the [OpenText Knowledge Center](https://knowledge.opentext.com).  Unfortunately you need to set up an account with OpenText to use the KC (and my guess is that you don't have an account).

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045614/recommend-reddot-cms-resources-books-fast-ways-of-learning) requests RedDot resources; hopefully one of them will be of use to you.

I personally don't have what you're looking for (I work with OpenText's Alchemy).

**EDIT:**
Here's a link to the RedDot product page (OpenText account required):
[OpenText Web Site Management (RedDot)](https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/llisapi.dll/Open/13001188)

Comment: we do have an account yeah.  Any idea where I might look?  Would save my guys hunting around.

Comment: @griegs Of course if you guys are enrolled in the Developers' Support program you can contact them directly; they were quite helpful when we were enrolled in it.  Even if you have regular phone support you might get lucky if you contact the right person.

Comment: @griegs Edited to add link to RedDot product page (with links to documentation and downloads).  Happy hunting!